# validations in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In MVC 3, it has DataAnnotations and also Custom Validation for validating on client side.
But I can use Jquery or Javascript to write my own validation to a .js file. I mean I use the script tag and type=text/javascript. So which one should I use, the one in MVC3 or the other?

Answer (score 1):

MVC's data annotations use jquery validation on the client side.  The point is that you use one method to do validation, and it works on both the server and the client.

You don't ever want to do only client-side validation, since a malicious attacker could bypass your javascript and send illegal values.  client-side validation is a nice thing for users, but should never be used without server side validation.

MVC does both with data annotations, and you only have to deal with it in one place.

Comment: I know that. Server side is important too. What i mean here is I want to display those message from validation by my own way. Cause the way that the MVC3 validations display sometimes is hard for display other( like the Html.ValidationSummary).

Comment: @user1260970 - I have no idea what you mean.  You should edit your question to include examples of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As Mystere Man pointed out, just use MVC's data annotations as it does both client and server side validation.

Your question is a bit vauge, but based on your comment to Mystere Man I think you want to know how you can change the validation messages yourself? If so, you can overload `@Html.ValidationSummary()` with a message like

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "My error message")
```

And on your models you can have a custom message for each of them by using an attribute like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name, this will not be displayed to others.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

You can also create custom validation, like a check box must be checked (since the `[Required]` attribute does not mean a `bool` must be `true`.) To do this and more, requires a bit more work but is very doable in the default validation.